# How to prevent of error 'Access Denied' while uploading a file in AWS bucket using Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to upload files in s3 bucket in asp.net mvc,
I am getting a permission error. Please, let me know where I am doing it wrong.I added IAM s3 policy also,
My bucket policy like below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::10250405040:user/someone"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::something/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "public-read"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My IAM policy

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code
The below variables declared in the controller class globally.
and sending it to the AmazonS3Client method which is in uploading method below

```
private static readonly string _awsAccessKey = "something";
private static readonly string _awsSecretKey = "something";
private static readonly string _bucketName = "something";
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult UploadImgsAndInsertIncident()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var uploadedFile = Request.Files[file];
                if (uploadedFile != null)
                {
                    AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
                    {
                        //its default region set by amazon
                        SignatureVersion = "4",
                        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
                        SignatureMethod = SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256
                    };

                    AmazonS3Client client;
                    using (client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, S3Config))
                    {

                        var request = new PutObjectRequest()
                        {
                            BucketName = _bucketName,
                            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,//PERMISSION TO FILE PUBLIC ACCESIBLE
                            Key = string.Format("UPLOADS/{0}", uploadedFile.FileName),
                            InputStream = uploadedFile.InputStream//SEND THE FILE STREAM
                        };

                        var response = client.PutObject(request);
                        if (Convert.ToString(response.HttpStatusCode) == "OK")
                        {
                            //do what you want..
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return Content("Success");
    }
```

at this line

```
var response = client.PutObject(request);
```

getting an exception i.e, 'Access Denied'.
so what could be the issue and what I am missing?

Comment: Is 'bucketName' your real bucket name or is this just an example? :)

Comment: its just an example

Comment: Your bucket policy specifies an IAM user. Do you run your code as a IAM user or using an IAM role? Can you post your IAM policy?

Comment: Yes, I run the code with IAM user.I added my IAM policy

Answer (score 1):

we will have to edit the Public Access Settings and then will need to set the first two options to false and the last two options to true for both your account and buckets.
for eg:

```
Manage public access control lists (ACLs):
        Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)
                False
        Remove public access granted through public ACLs (Recommended)
                False

Manage public bucket policies:
        Block new public bucket policies (Recommended)
                True
        Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies (Recommended)
                True
```